# iOS Auto refresh a view element

Tags: ios

I am fetching data from an API and storing into a file.
I am fetching data after every 10 minutes using `NSTimer`.

It works well for me.

However, I want to auto-refresh one of my views whenever I fetch data. I am able to call a function of my view and log the data, but I am unable to update my labels' text using the following code:

```
UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController alloc] init];

vc.showLabels;
```

Does anybody know how to refresh a visible ViewController?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think [self.view setNeedsDisplay] will update your view

Comment: why are you again allocating the instance of the viewcontroller ? That causes the issue

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem using timer

```
NSTimer timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:refreshTime target:self selector:@selector(refreshPage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)refreshPage
{

    // If user currently navigate on TableView page then refresh stock page.
    if([currentViewController isKindOfClass:[CustomViewController class]])
    {
        [currentViewController fetchDataFromServer];
    }
    else
    {
        // else fetch stock data and update the storage file.
        [self refreshStockDetails];
    }    
}
```